# Sending Private Messages to Users using Socket.IO

Tags: socket.io, sails.js

I am new to Sails and Socket.IO currently I am building an chat application where users can send private messages to each other. I manage to build a basic chat application but it broadcast updates to all users who are connected to Sails application.

Could you please suggest me a way to send messages to particular user which connected to the sails application.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sails incorporates Socket.io without changing it a lot, so you can use standard Socket.io tools within Sails.

In your particular case we are probably talking about [rooms](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Rooms) functionality.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
   let isSocket = req.isSocket
    if(isSocket) {
        let id = sails.sockets.id(req.socket)
        sails.sockets.emit(id,'privateMessage',{payload:"hello"})
   }
```